# Can't hit REST endpoint when VPN is on

Tags: java, ssl, networking, vpn, okhttp

I have a very elementary knowledge of networks.  Please ELI5

I have some Java code that hits a test REST endpoint (GET).  `https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2`

When running my code in my local environment and I have my corporate VPN off I'm able to hit that endpoint without error.

When I turn on my corporate VPN I start getting odd errors, specifically `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake`

What could possibly be causing my java code to break when connected to a VPN?

What's even weirder  is when I enter the endpoint in my browser while the VPN is on, I'm able to hit the endpoint as everything is normal.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                  .url("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")
                  .build();

try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
    return response.body().string();
}
```

### EDIT

I have access to two proxies, the one used in my browser generated a 400 error and the other one works in my code.  Why is a proxy required when using a VPN and what would differ between my 2 proxies, why would one generate a 400 in my code and not the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly believe you need to make a call via proxy as this is happening in a corporate network. This issue is not occurring in the browser because of browser uses VPN settings to make an HTTP/HTTPS call. Adding a proxy setting in the code would solve the problem.

Comment: You are partially correct, we have access to 2 proxy.  If I use the proxy used in my browser I get a 400 error code in my code.  If I use my second proxy  not being used by the browser it seems to work.  Can you provide me a bit of context as to why a proxy is required when using a VPN and if you can why one generate a 400 and the other works.  What differs in those 2 proxies?

Comment: Proxies are the way to connect to the outside world. All request will go through the proxy and certain one will be blocked based on the policies configured. There are different policies for incoming and outgoing requests as well. Two different proxies might have two different intent based on the company's infrastructure requirement.